# How to read into a table in access with python

Tags: python, excel, ms-access

I created an Access file and inside made a table that has a column of yes/no checkbox in it. I want to create a python file to check off the checkbox (yes).

How do I locate the specific table and cell in the access file?

I want to go to that cell and check off the yes/no box and move on to the next cell.

I hear it's best to use pypyodbc. I don't understand how to use that and get to that specific table in Microsoft Access file.

Comment: Emily is not so clear your question. Can you insert more details ?

Comment: let me know if that is more clear.

Comment: ODBC is a connector that allows you to  execute SQL query on your data source. I guess you have to create an ODBC data source. See this link: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Administer-ODBC-data-sources-b19f856b-5b9b-48c9-8b93-07484bfab5a7 and after you have to use PyPyODBC for connecting with your data source and executing SQL query on it. See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557879/pypyodbc-help-to-find-tutorials-for-begining